# Preserving style during copy past in JS. (how get stile from clipboard)

Tags: javascript, styles, editor, clipboard

Yesterday I wrote an article about "Sliding Window" Algorithm in MicrosoftVSC editor in `*.md` format, later I copy/pasted this article from [md preview](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_markdown-preview) (It is a decorated text, not a Markdown code) to a medium editor. And I been surprised that style and headings are saved.

The question is: What parts of JS recognize the design of text from clipboard?

P.S. When I insert this copied text with styles inside `Notepad` or `Untitled file of MVC` it is just a plane text. How did the `Medium` editor recognized the style, what is the data format in clipboard?

When I again copy this plain text from a notepad, and insert it inside the Medium editor the styles are not appears (as they should). But it's curious how do this styles passed and where do they saved.

Comment: `*.md` suggests you used [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown#Example), apparently without realizing it. (which happens to be what I'm using to style and include the link in this comment)

Comment: Yes I did use Markdown, but I copy from `preview` where it is just decorated text and there are no any Markdown code.

Comment: I did what you did and pasted into Word. Using the context menu I can paste as "keep formatting" or "just text". So the styling is definitely in the clipboard, and it appears to use some universal/Microsoft format. I also tried posting into Wordpress and again, the formatting persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer on this question lies in [DataTranswer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) object that holds information about [paste](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event) event. This object holds different versions of saved text. One version is `plain/text` second version is `text/html`. The `text/html` versions contains a decoration.

```
console.log("Checking paste operation.")
document.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
        console.log("The Past is Happens");
        console.log(e.clipboardData.types);
        ['text/plain','text/html'].forEach( format =>{
          console.log(`Format: ${format}`);
          console.log(e.clipboardData.getData(format));
        });
    });
```